# Reading the multiline text box in Windows AS it is Entered by user

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a static width of the multiline text box.
When i Continuously type long text it is showing in single line in the code behind when i try to read.
I wanted to use this data to print in the component One {C1PrintDocument} . As user entered . but it showing everything in the same line and it is getting truncated .
I am dealing japense as well as English language .

Below is the same of the JP text.
Text Example: "れはれはれはれはれはれはれ1はれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれははれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれ6はれはれれれれれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれれれれれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれはれれれれれ7はれはれはれはれはれはれは"  .

I want to internally identify the new line as user enter in the system.
i tried using Environment.NewLine . but it doesn't work because this is the continuous text.
Help me to read the text as it is appeared in the windows text box to print that.

Comment: Is it winforms or asp.net? Can't be both...

Comment: i have windows form where i am trying this

Comment: **Show your code.** If we can't see what you're doing, there's no way we can help.

Comment: Nothing in code yet , my requirement is that What ever user enter into this Multi line textbox whether it is ENG or JPN or CHN , it can be with newline or continues word. i need to wrap that into the text box again as it is . but when i read that in C# code it is in one line .

Comment: I Got the solution. i have to create the algorithm for the solution below is the steps to do so , as JP character have 2 bytes of data and ENG have 1 byte of data , i split-ed the above String into the Character array  . and looped character array and got its byte in the key value pair Collection . i also calculated the destination windows width . and tried to fit that much byte of data in one line.

Comment: this is the algorithim :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Algorithm i wrote to solve this problem is as below :

```
// <summary>
        // Functions takes the Large text and split the string according to the maximum length of the string per line.
        // </summary>
        // <param name="strData">String Data</param>
        // <param name="intMaxSize">Maximum Size of the row</param>
        // <returns></returns>
        public static List<string> GetLines(string strData, int intMaxSize)
        {
            List<string> strReturn = new List<string>();
            string[] strLineSplited = strData.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int intNoOfLine = 0; intNoOfLine < strLineSplited.Length; intNoOfLine++)
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<char, int>> listOfChar = new List<KeyValuePair<char, int>>();
                string strValue = strLineSplited[intNoOfLine];
                StringBuilder sbSingleLine = new StringBuilder();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
                {
                    char[] charArr = strValue.ToCharArray();
                    int intCharCount = 0;
                    byte[] bascii = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strValue);
                    for (int intCounter = 0; intCounter < bascii.Length; intCounter++)
                    {
                        int intASCIICode = bascii[intCounter];
                        if (intASCIICode >= 32 && intASCIICode <= 62)
                        {
                            listOfChar.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(charArr[intCounter], 1));
                        }
                        else if (intASCIICode >= 65 && intASCIICode <= 122)
                        {
                            listOfChar.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(charArr[intCounter], 1));
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listOfChar.Add(new KeyValuePair<char, int>(charArr[intCounter], 2));
                        }
                    }
                    bool bFlag = true;
                    foreach (var charValue in listOfChar)
                    {
                        intCharCount += Convert.ToInt32(charValue.Value);
                        if (intCharCount < intMaxSize)
                        {
                            sbSingleLine.Append(charValue.Key);
                            bFlag = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            sbSingleLine.Append(charValue.Key);
                            strReturn.Add(sbSingleLine.ToString());
                            sbSingleLine.Length = 0;
                            sbSingleLine.Capacity = 0;
                            intCharCount = 0;
                            bFlag = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (intCharCount < intMaxSize && bFlag)
                    {
                        strReturn.Add(sbSingleLine.ToString());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    strReturn.Add(sbSingleLine.ToString());
                }
            }
            return strReturn;
        }
```